# Angular ng-resource configuration binding with object?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ngresource

It's been several hour i'm trying to figure this very simple issue.
I have ng-model attribute  which bind to payment object (ng-model="payment.newPaymentLine.method"), like this one:

```
<div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label>Payment Method:</label>
                    <select class="form-control"
                            ng-model="payment.newPaymentLine.method"
                            ng-options="paymentMethod for paymentMethod  in payment.paymentMethods" required></select>
                </div>
```

I was wondering how can i configure ng-resource which bind with that property, i try the following format("@payment.newPaymentLine.method") but it doesn't work:

```
 classContext.bankRepository = classContext.salesOrderResource(
                    classContext.appConfig.getApiEndPoint(classContext.appConfig.apiPath.payment) + "/:PaymentMethod/banks"
                    , { PaymentMethod: "@payment.newPaymentLine.method" });
```

btw i'm using type script 1.5

Answer (score 0):

I think i have misunderstood ng-resource concept, the parameter should bind to the data object properties not with the context object